# How to get unique page views in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get unique page views like if the page is already visited it should not be counted.

So the solution I thought was like on each reload save the page path to a localStorage in an array and on next reload check if the page path already exists in the localStorage array dont increment else increment the count by 1. If there are 500 pages in website then we need to store all 500 page path in localStorage which would be high is what I felt. This is the scenario when the user opens all the 500 pages of the website

The requirement is we need to get all this data and send it along with form submission to a third party server.

Any better solutions?

Comment: Sure, that sounds like the most straightforward solution, if you really want to do this client-side.

Comment: Your localStorage will finally fill up. Use back-end storage.

Comment: Couldnt you use google analytics or something similar?

Comment: We are using signal analytics and the person from signal has asked me to do it from client side

Comment: you can give a unique Id for every page

Comment: @SusheelSingh - some person told you to do this on the client.. and you listened? it's much better to ignore such "advice" then to act upon it

Comment: The requirement is we need to get all this data and send it along with form submission to a third party server.

Answer (score 5):

Doing this client-side is sub-optimal. I suggest doing this on your server, based on IP and using a cookie on the client to track unique clients, so that you can evaluate which pages they have viewed etc.

If you absolutely *have* to do this client-side, using localStorage might be slower and/or problematic due to limitations. You could look into [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), as well.

Comment: You can use a cookie (or localStorage) to store a unique hash for each client, so you can differentiate multiple clients under the same IP, so then you can use the combination of IP + clientCookie to uniquely identify the client.

Comment: Got you but my requirement is we need to get all this data and send it along with form submission to a third party server.